# hide / display dom elements based on selection

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation, advanced-custom-fields

I've been struggling with this for a long time now. Let me try to explain it as clear as possible:

Im creating a Wordpress site (from scratch) for users to post finished products, reviews and more stuff. The posting takes place in the backend of Wordpress.
Im using ACF Pro for setting up completely custom post edit pages.

When a user posts a new review, he/she should select the product (let's call it 'target product') where the review is about from a ACF relationship field.
I would like the rest of the ACF fields to stay hidden until the user selects at least one target product.

The ACF relationship field has two div's with the following class:

1. `choices` is the div that contains all the products in a `ul` with `li` items. Each list item is a product
2. `values` is the div that contains all the picked products in a `ul` with `li` items. Each list item is a picked product.

Products can be 'picked' by clicking on them in the `choices` div. this means that when adding a new review, the `ul` in the `values` div contains **no** list items.

So I need Javascript to perform a function like this:

```
var $hiders = $('#excerpt, #intro, #text, #conclusion, #rating, #pros, #cons');
var x = $('#target-product .values ul.list li').length;
if ( x == 0 ) {
    hiders.fadeOut(500);
} else {
    hiders.fadeIn(500);
}
```

everytime a list item in the `choices` div is clicked **and** everytime a `li` in the `values` div is removed (there's a delete button next to the list item here).

`$hiders` contains the div's to be hidden if `x = 0`

Since this is a crucial function (user depend on this to work in order to proceed) I need 100% compatibility with all the browsers. 
Am not sure on what the best approach in order to make this work.

Thanks!

**Edit**
changed `x = 0` to `x == 0`

Comment: Your `if` statement is missing an `=`, should be `x == 0` - `x = 0` will always pass.

Comment: The x=0 is called an assignment statement and not a logical expression. The assignment statements are not used for logical expressions which is required for the "if" conditions. So, use what @tymeJV wrote (x==0).

Comment: Thanks for that guys! stupid of me not to notice it because I used it correctly before. But the big question is, how can I make Javascript fire the code above when the above mentioned list items change? Im stuck on that part.